# Angularjs Multiple Select: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, multiple-select

I have tried many variations but nothing seem to work.

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at select.js:1560
at m.$broadcast (angular.js:18487)
at Object.ctrl.select (select.js:673)
at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15358), <anonymous>:4:453)
at e (angular.js:26994)
at b.$eval (angular.js:18161)
at b.$apply (angular.js:18261)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:26999)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
```

My code in the HTML part is:

```
<label for="addRecipient" class="bold">Additional Recipients:</label>
<ui-select multiple ng-model="addRecipient.selection" theme="bootstrap" title="Choose Recipients" class="multipleSelect">
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select Additional Recipients...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="additional in addRecipients | filter:$select.search">
 {{additional.name}}
</ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

And in my controller:

```
$scope.addRecipient = {}; 
$scope.addRecipients =  [];
$.each(success.data.d.results, function (ind, val) {
  $scope.addRecipients.push({'name': val.Title, 'email':val.Email});
});
```

I can see the options to select in my select, however every time I click in any option, I get that error. Here is the dropdown showing the info from success.data.d.results:

[image: dropdown]

Comment: That means your array is empty

Comment: That isnt your full controller, my assumption is success.data.d.results is empty thus your $.each is not iteratiing

Comment: Please, can you share controller, directive, Etc.

Comment: The array has values. I am getting the results on the dropdown. I will add an image in my post.

Comment: Everything works now. And I am glad we found out how to solve this type of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how my code looks now and it is working. Thank you @NTP for the hint!

```
<label for="addRecipient" class="bold">Additional Recipients:</label>
<ui-select multiple ng-model="addRecipient.selected" theme="bootstrap" title="Choose Recipients" class="multipleSelect">
   <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Additional Recipients...">{{$item.Title}}</ui-select-match>
   <ui-select-choices repeat="additional in addRecipients | filter:$select.search">
       {{additional.Title}}
</ui-select-choices>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.addRecipient = {}; 
$scope.addRecipients = [];
```

Dropdown values:

```
$scope.addRecipients = success.data.d.results;
```

Getting selected values:

```
//add Recipient
var addRecipients;
if ($scope.addRecipient.selected && $scope.addRecipient.selected !='undefined'){
     things = [];
     console.log($scope.addRecipient.selected);
     for (var key in $scope.addRecipient.selected) {
          if (key < $scope.addRecipient.selected.length) {
                 things.push($scope.addRecipient.selected[key].Email) ;
          }
      }
      addRecipients = things;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I received the error when the data in dropdownList was empty. Once you initialize value in dropdownList it works just fine.
this.dropdownList=[];

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your selection array,

```
$scope.addRecipient = {}; 
$scope.addRecipient.selection = [];
```

Comment: Thank you! Thanks to your answer I was able to figure it out. It didn't work putting $scope.addRecipient = {}; but when I changed it to an array it worked. Your solution didn't work when I tried but it was what led me to get it working. Thank you!

Comment: I am glad I was able to help.

Comment: I appreciate it! I was getting crazy with that.